# How to speed up raster2pgsql?

Tags: postgis, raster, dem, raster2pgsql

I'm trying to upload a 37 GB raster dataset to PostGIS. The raster is out-of-db (-R option), so the actual pixel values are not stored in PostGIS. I'm using this command:

`raster2pgsql -s 25833 -C -I -R -t auto /data/norway/terrain/10m/*.dem dem.10m | psql -h localhost -U postgres -p 5432 -d norway`

Everything works fine, but it's veeery slow: There are 254 raster files in my folder, and in 24 hours only 8 are added. With this speed it will take me a month to upload the dataset!

Is there any way I could speed up the process?

Answer (score 4):

I came across this question while looking up ways to speed up ingestion of raster tiles as well. I wrote a script using [Gnu Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) to multi-thread the process, which sped up the ingestion of about 160gb of tif raster tiles from days to about 6 hours.

```
#!/bin/sh

listOfTiles() {
    for i in $(find . -type f -iname '*.tif'); do
        if ! grep -qi ${i##*/} copied; then
            rasters+=("$i")
            echo "adding $i"
        else
            echo "skipping $i"
        fi;
    done
}

uploadRasters() {
    parallel --jobs 200% --bar 'raster2pgsql -Y -b 1 -s 4326 -a -F -t 40x40 {} dem | psql && echo "{/} $(date)" >> copied' ::: $1
}
```

Even on my low-power xeon hardware, the performance increase in notable. Note also that no constraints or indexes are created during ingestion and that the tile dimensions are manually specified. Copy is used instead of insert, which seemed to prevent a deadlock.

Comment: When I ran raster2pgsql in parallel concurrently, even with `-Y` I still got `ERROR:  deadlock detected
 DETAIL:  Process 2145 waits for ShareLock on relation 19783 of database 16385; blocked by process 2133.
 Process 2133 waits for ShareLock on relation 19783 of database 16385; blocked by process 2145.
 HINT:  See server log for query details.
 ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block`

Comment: @AndrewHarvey this is a little late... BUT this problems still persists. What helped me is using the following option:

`-e  Execute each statement individually, do not use a transaction.`

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the -C that often takes up most of the processing.  Just to verify that is the case, can youtry without the -C.  -C just adds constraints which are queryable from raster_columns.  You may or may not need that but can alsoways add after if you do. Though given -C runs after the load that may not be the issue you are running into.

How big are you tiles and how much mem you have?  Even though you are using -R it still may be useful to use the -t option (for tiling).  Tiling as I recall of a -R just creates a virtual tile which may mean when its oding other checks, it may just inspeact that part of the tile making performance better even in load.

Comment: I've tried different options, leaving out -C didn't make a big difference, but dropping the -R option did. So it seems that storing the raster out-of-db really slows down the loading process, at least on my computer. I hoped to save some space on my precious hard drive, instead I'm now uploading the rasters to PostGIS, and keep the originals on an external drive. Each of the 256 tiles is 150 MB so there might be a memory issue.

Comment: Could be a bug in our out-db handling.  Worth posting to our ticket tracker - http://postgis.net/support/  The outdb support is not as stress tested as in-db so it might be a real issue.  If you can provide an example dataset or link to one that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is 7 year old question, however I struggled to find answer to this exact problem and because this is the first result when searching this issue I thought to add my findings here.

The slowness seems to happen because of the `NODATA` checks during the upload process. You can completely disable the `NODATA` checks with `-k` argument for `raster2pgsql`. However, this means that `raster2pgsql` uploads all possible tiles to the database, even the ones where all pixel values are `NODATA`. This is probably not what you want.

Instead, if you are working with uncompressed GeoTIFF files, you can try to set the environment variable `export GTIFF_DIRECT_IO=YES`. I'm not entirely sure why this works, but it provides a massive speed up. It is documented in GeoTIFF GDAL driver here: https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html

> GTIFF_DIRECT_IO =YES/NO: Can be set to YES to use specialized RasterIO() implementations when reading un-compressed TIFF files (un-tiled only in GDAL 2.0, both un-tiled and tiled in GDAL 2.1) to avoid using the block cache. Setting it to YES even when the optimized cases do not apply should be safe (generic implementation will be used). Default value:NO

The option can improve the upload speed of large GeoTIFF files by more than 10 times and still keep the `NODATA` checks.

A benchmark guide for the option can be found here if you want to test it in your own environment: https://github.com/janne-alatalo/slow-raster2pgsql-workaround

The option seems to speed up in-db data upload too.

Also you can use it with compressed out-db GeoTIFF files too by first uncompressing the GeoTIFF file, then uploading it, and then replacing the uncompressed file with the old compressed file. PostGIS doesn't mind that the file compression is changed afterwards.